# How can i insert data into table using Dataset?

Tags: c#, mysql, dataset

I have two tables in MYSQL database which contains same Columns by counting and names ,
i have all data from first table into DataSet but now how can i Copy this dt into second table if possible ?

Comment: Sounds like you want to copy the contents of your populated dataset into a MySql table. Is that correct?

Comment: yes i want copy all data from detaset into second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Copy only new rows.

```
DataSet addedDataSet= customerDataSet.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
```

// Copy all changes.

```
DataSet changeDataSet = customerDataSet.GetChanges();
```

//Create full copy

```
DataSet copyDataSet = customerDataSet.Copy();
```

Comment: Ok now two datasets are same but how to send into database this copyDataset ?